# Json.dump() does not have the expected output

Tags: python, json

I have a set of results in python and I want to convert them into a JSON file, so I use json.dump(), as below:

```
with open('pass_blocked.json','w') as outPassBlocked:
        json.dump(pass_blocked_results,outPassBlocked, indent=4)
```

However, the file that is created does not have the JSON format that I expected.How can I create a correct JSON file ? The one I get is this:

```
[
    683, 
    {
        "nightly_result": null, 
        "current_result": "PASS", 
        "testrail_id": "12645"
    }, 
    2056, 
    {
        "nightly_result": null, 
        "current_result": "BLOCK", 
        "testrail_id": "13200"
    }, 
    1033, 
    {
        "nightly_result": null,  
        "current_result": "BLOCK", 
        "testrail_id": "9713"
    }, 
    1036, 
    {
        "nightly_result": null, 
        "current_result": "PASS", 
        "testrail_id": "1016748"
    }
]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: That json seems to be OK. What's the input you are giving? Whats the format you were expecting? We need more details to answer.

Comment: What's your *expected* JSON format? The JSON you posted is valid JSON.

Comment: I need to get something like:"683": { "nightly_result": null,...etc }

Comment: That comma should not be there

Comment: Can you show us the content of `pass_blocked_results`?

Comment: And the input you are giving to the function? I think the problem is that you are not passing the input correctly, otherwise it would be OK

Comment: Presumably `pass_blocked_result` is a list whose elements are alternating between integers and dictionaries. If you want to dump a dictionary instead, then make `pass_blocked_result` into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I insist on the error of the input (thing I said in comments). However, you could try changing the input you give to dump, to remake the list the way you want it. Try something like this.

```
with open('pass_blocked.json','w') as outPassBlocked:
    pass_blocked_results = list(map(lambda i: {pass_blocked_results[i]: pass_blocked_results[i+1]}, 
                                    range(0, len(pass_blocked_results), 2)))
    json.dump(pass_blocked_results,outPassBlocked, indent=4)
```

You should still look how are you creating your list though.